# Integrate $\int_0^\infty x(y+x)^{n-2}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How would one integrate this $$\int_0^\infty x(y+x)^{n-2}dx \quad$$I can't think of ways of going about solving this.

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts? ($u=x$, $dv=(y+x)^{n-2}$.)

Comment: When ever you see integrand with $(.)^n$, think almost atomatically about integration by parts to get a recurrence relation.

Comment: Yeah, the resulting $\frac{x(y+x)^{n-1}}{n-1} \text{evaluated at }\infty \text{ is } \infty$. Hence I'm stuck, I could have integrated it wrong.

Comment: It is assumed that $y$ is a constant? Presumably there are restrictions on $n$?

Comment: @Jim y and n are both fixed constants, n is a positive integer

Comment: For $n$, isn't there going to be a problem if $n \ge 1$, since then the integral diverges? You must require $n \le 1$ then you wouldn't have $\frac{x(y+x)^{n-1}}{n-1} \text{evaluated at }\infty \text{ is } \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x(y+x)^{n-2}\space\text{d}x=\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{0}^{a}x(y+x)^{n-2}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=y+x$ and $\text{d}u=\text{d}x$.

This gives a new lower bound $u=y+0=y$ and upper bound $u=y+a$:

---

$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{y}^{y+a}u^{n-2}(u-y)\space\text{d}u=$$
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{y}^{y+a}\left[u^{n-1}-yu^{n-2}\right]\space\text{d}u=$$
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\left[\int_{y}^{y+a}u^{n-1}\space\text{d}u-y\int_{y}^{y+a}u^{n-2}\space\text{d}u\right]=$$
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\left[\left[\frac{u^n}{n}\right]_{y}^{y+a}-\left[\frac{u^{n-1}}{n-1}\right]_{y}^{y+a}\right]=$$
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\left[\frac{(a+y)^n-y^n}{n}-\frac{(a+y)^{n-1}-y^{n-1}}{n-1}\right]=\frac{y^n}{n(n-1)}$$

This is true when:

$$\Re[n]<0\space\wedge\space\Re[y]>0\space\wedge\space2\arg\left[\frac{1}{y}\right]\le\pi$$

Comment: Does this answer simplify to the one on wolfram alpha. Because that's the answer that would fit well within the context I'm trying to solve it for. If so, how?

Comment: Within the context of my problem n is a fixed positive integer

Comment: You, see that the integral does not converge for a positive integer! Because $\Re[n]<0$

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea with a substitution:

$$(y+x)^{n-2}=y^{n-2}\left(1+\frac xy\right)^{n-2}\implies \text{substitute}\;\;\,t:=1+\frac xy\;,\;\;dt=\frac{dx}y\implies$$

$$\int_0^\infty x(y+x)^{n-2}dx=y^{n-1}\int_1^\infty t^{n-2}y(t-1)\;dt=$$

$$=y^n\int_1^\infty \left(t^{n-1}-t^{n-2}\right)dt=\left.y^n\lim_{b\to\infty}\left(\frac1n\,t^n-\frac1{n-1}\,t^{n-1}\right)\right|_1^b=$$$${}$$

$$=\begin{cases}\text{doesn't exist finitely},\;&|t|\ge1\\{}\\y^n\left(-\frac1n+\frac1{n-1}\right)=\frac{y^n}{n(n-1)},\;&|t|<1\end{cases}$$